# Sex education vs sexuality education

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, vocabulary

What are the differences between "sex education" and "sexuality education"?

Comment: Sex education talks about the act, body parts and how they are use in sex and everything else that pertains. Sexuality education focuses on your feelings, your attractions towards the opposite or same sex.

Comment: "Sexuality" may also cover general discussion of LGBT and gender topics.

Comment: Analogous to the difference between car mechanics and the design of a transport network?

Comment: @WS2 That would be a terrific analogy - if cars did but possess gender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point of sex education is to learn about the male and female genitalia. This course usually includes information about contraception. Sexuality education talks about different sexual preferences; not the act of having sex.

Comment: Can you add references that show people use these phrases taht way?